# Modifying a plastic electrical box for structured wiring usage

Tags: electrical, wiring, data-wiring

I'm building a new home and wished to install structured wiring (2 cat 6, 2 rg6 and 2 fiber optic cable). In pricing the orange open front and rear boxes, I found them ridiculously expensive. The open back is need for extra wiring.

My question is: it against any code to remove the back on a plastic box to accommodate the structured wiring. Would it have to be painted orange?

It doesn't affect fit, form or function.

Comment: Do an end-run around the whole problem and use stout steel boxes, ideally drawn not welded type, using extension boxes if you want open backs.  I agree *all* plastic boxes, even the blue ones, are flimsy and they only make sense if the goal is to save money, except they don't, as you are discovering!  Basically their job is to not tear out of the wall, hold screws and not strip out, and contain arcs and sparks. Steel does *all that better*.  Plastic boxes SMH...

Comment: Even better, use EMT or PVC conduit in certain areas, to make it stupid easy to pull additional cable later.

Answer (score 1):

google MPLS. that's what we use in commercial buildings it's also called a "mud ring"...basically a thin metal ring that is threaded to hold the faceplate on. use a level, trace an outline, (very carefully)cut  hole with a drywall saw, bend the tabs align the screw and tighten down. holds like 10 lbs in drywall. least expensive option, can't see it when faceplate is installed.

Comment: Wait, you just use a mud ring of the sort intended for putting on a steel box?  And you just float it in the drywall? That's great until the first time you trip over your cable TV cord and tear it out of the wall...

Comment: The basis for the question is cost. MLPS is the most cost efficient solution,  Millions of commercial offices, schools and homes are installed like this.  You definitely need more room in the box if you are installing fiber, coax, and, cat 6.( it's super hard to cram all that into a single gang box). I have seen the backs sawed off a 3 gang boxes in commercial applications. Codes and inspectors seem to be arbitrary about low voltage. The National Electric Code is vague.

Comment: http://store.grouponenw.com//v/vspfiles/photos/CDY_MPLS-2T.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Not usually against code to cut the back off if used for low voltage, and I don't think color would matter, but building codes are usually goverened by the city and could be different in different areas, so be sure to call the local city people and check.

I second the MPLS metal ring on cost savings(I get them for about $1.25 each.) Be sure to mark your box location on the floor, drywall guys love to cover up wall boxes and you may need to go back and find yours.  But think about next year, how much would you pay later to get an additional cable into a room after the drywall goes up?  If you can afford to install every cable you'll ever need at each location, then do that (why quibble about the cost of boxes then?)

I recommend all my friends building new houses install the blue flexible plastic conduit referred to as "smurftube" and run that back to their network equipment area. It's flexible and easy to install, and can be found cheapest when bought in rolls online.  If you have electricity on site, a corded drill and an auger bit will make the installation quick, use a paddle bit if you're going cordless. 
 Put a string in each tube from end to end (hint: use a vaccuum to suck the string through the "smurftube"), and then pull in only what you need to each location.  Only need one coax cable, just pull that one in.  Don't forget to also pull in a new string to replace the one you're pulling out when installing cables.

This method minimizes the installation cost by you not installing cable that may not ever get used, and future-proofs your home for reorganizing the space.  This is especially good for 2-story houses, as getting between floors after the construction is complete is difficult.

I recommend two places in rooms where signal might be needed (bedrooms, offices, family rooms, etc) and don't forget a way to get your internet connection to your equipment area.  Be sure to size the conduit diameter as to how many cable you might need at a location.  I charge about $250 on average to install cables into houses post-construction, and the price goes up if they're hard to get to due to roof pitch, multiple floors, etc., and there's always a risk of falling through the ceiling, and other damage to airducts, plumbing, electrical...  At the very least, a conduit up to the attic space will help later.  "Oh I'll never need all that"...but remember when you came home and your spouse had rearranged all the furniture in a room, or several rooms, along with the TVs and all the art on the walls(nail holes,) and declared it, "Just perfect!" this would help.

Good luck!